Ubuntu can not access internet in WSL2 Windows 10
So I have been trying to play around with wsl and linux on windows for about 10 days now. No matter which Lunx I install on wsl, it can never access internet, no ping, no apt update, nothing. Ubuntue, Debian, Kali, Opensuse, Oracle Linux, tried all of the options, none of them can access internet. For the last 10 days, I have tried every solution I found all over internet, including some from this site. None of them working.
I made a Hyper-V vm and installed Ubuntu on it, it works fine, tried Kali, works fine. I use android emulator to play some games that works perfectly fine. So the problem doesn't seem to be vm related.
I simply tried every thing, none works. It has become a weird obsession for me now. So I wonder if anyone here is suffering the same problem, if so, how did you fix it?
Ohh Marry Christmas by the way. Cheers.
EDIT: I forgot to mention something very important, there is a "solution" to this, that is to turn back to wsl version 1 and converting the linux distro to wsl version 1 as well. However, this "solution" causes a lot of problems if we try to use a linux GUI, and crashes a lot when we use GUI apps. So I am looking for an actual solution that can keep me on wsl version 2 and fix these problems.

It looks like the problem is not specific to Ubuntu (as you say in your question). You may want to report a bug to Microsoft as WSL is a part of Windows.

There is already a thread up on wsl github and multiple on microsoft learn regarding this very topic. No solution from there work. That is why I have posted here, in case someone here found something. Thanks for the reply.

So there is sort of a "solution" to this, it requires access to WSL Settings icon on star menu, if it is not there, we need to uninstall wsl,, restart pc, install again and restart pc until we get that icon. Once we have access to WSL settings, we should go to the Networking section from the left panel, disable everything in there and select "VirtioProxy" as Networking Mode. Start wsl now and enter any of the installed distro and we will be able to update linux and access internet from linux. But it ruins lots of other networking features. So it is sort of a "solution".
